# How to Configure Approle with Jenkins for generating STS token from vault

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I am integrating Hashicorp vault with Jenkins and trying to generate dynamic secrets using assume role but getting permission denied error.

I followed these steps for creating policy and jenkins code but did not help.

https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/identity-access-management/iam-authentication

https://github.com/jenkinsci/hashicorp-vault-plugin

I am not sure what vault policy should be defined.

### vault policy

```
path "auth/approle/login" capabilities = [ "create", "read" ]

path "secret/aws*" capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list", "sudo"]
```

### Error

```
> Caused: com.datapipe.jenkins.vault.exception.VaultPluginException:
> could not read from vault: Vault responded with HTTP status code: 403
> Response body: {"errors":["1 error occurred:\n\t* permission
> denied\n\n"]}  at path: aws/sts/VaultTFE-Sandbox
```

Please help!!!

Comment: the path that gives you error is `aws/sts/VaultTFE-Sandbox` and the path that you allow in the policy is `secret/aws*`. Maybe there is something there.

Comment: You are right, After making changes to the path it worked like a charm.

Comment: path "aws/sts/*" {
  capabilities = [ "read" ]

Comment: good stuff, ill add it as an answer and you can mark it as resolved

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the error message mentions

> at path: aws/sts/VaultTFE-Sandbox

but your policy mentions

```
path "secret/aws*"
```

That should probably be changed to

```
path "aws/sts/VaultTFE-Sandbox"
```